# html a onclick exploits causing antivirus to go crazy

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, antivirus, exploit

Does anyone know why things like:

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript_foo_function(1,'foo',34); return false;">
```

Cause most antivirus (such as McAfee mcshield.exe) to go haywire? What is the exploit that they are looking to protect against? Many programs (mcafee and norton) do some insane calculations that seem to exponentially increase with the number of links, a few hundred links like that one a page can result in 2 minutes before the page is useable. I wonder what they are doing?

Once I changed them to `<A href="javascript:javascript_foo_function(1,'foo',34);">` antivirus had no problem and didn't cause excessive CPU usage.

Comment: That shouldn't make McAfee go haywire. Anyone else can confirm? I don't see it.

Comment: by nothing happened you mean, the Antiviruses are still crazy? Or nothing happened means they calmed down?

Comment: Can you describe what exactly happens? Are you really sure it's related to the number of links?

Comment: They calmed down to nothing. If I have the onlick one 200 times on a page with different numbers as parameters mcafee goes 100% CPU for about 90 seconds. Once I use only the href the scan is extremely fast.  Norton isn't as bad but it still has a noticable delay and goes 100% CPU for a few seconds. The problem is that in corporate enviroments everyone is using mcafee so alot of people are getting crippled by this - which I found very interesting. But we are talking about mcafee... the program that closes TCP connections that send raw text like "select top 5" .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why a virus scanner would react in this way, but to offer an approach for a possible workaround: Try not using `onclick` directly, but define the events in an external JS file. Maybe that'll pass without triggering whatever "guard" mechanism seems to think this is suspicious.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="link_1">
```

In a separate JS file that you embed at the end of the document:

```
document.getElementById("link_1").onclick = function() { 
 javascript_foo_function(1,'foo',34); 
 return false;
}
```

now if the virus scanners think they're fighting a real problem here, and if they are smart, they won't be fooled by this. But I'm having trouble using "Norton" and "Smart" in one sentence, and there clearly is no security problem in the first place, so it may as well work. Try it out.